# Scala Play 2.4.x controller class chaining?

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm using the [play-slick-3.0](https://github.com/wsargent/play-slick-3.0) project as base for migrating a legacy Play project I have. The legacy `controller.Application` used to be an object and now is a class, likewise all the other controller implementations were objects and now are classes. The legacy project was doing "controller chaining" i.e. Application delegates to other controllers:

```
class Application extends Controller {
...
  def uploadDo(context: String) = { implicit request ⇒ 
    // a lot of boilerplate code common to all contexts
    context match {
      case "aum" ⇒ AumController.uploadDo(storedFile)
      case "portfolio" ⇒ PortfolioController.uploadDo(storedFile)
      case "price" ⇒ PriceController.uploadDo(storedFile)
    }
    // more boilerplate code common to all contexts
  }
}
```

The problem is that I can no longer do that kind of delegation because AumController is a class and not an object anymore. I can't also define an associated object because these classes get instantiated and dependencies are injected by the framework ... see for instance the [Application.scala](https://github.com/wsargent/play-slick-3.0/blob/master/app/controllers/Application.scala) in that same project, it is not possible to instantiate it directly.

How can I fix/migrate the delegation issue above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably make use of **reverse routing strategy**

```
  class Application extends Controller {
   ...
   def uploadDo(context: String) = { implicit request ⇒ 
    // a lot of boilerplate code common to all contexts
    context match {
      case "aum" ⇒ routes.AumController.uploadDo(storedFile)
      case "portfolio" ⇒ routes.PortfolioController.uploadDo(storedFile)
      case "price" ⇒ routesPriceController.uploadDo(storedFile)
    }
    // more boilerplate code common to all contexts
  }
}
```

Comment: If this answers your question , please accept the answer .

Comment: I get the error: `value AumController is not a member of object controllers.routes`

Comment: This works if all your controllers are defined in controllers package. In case you have your controllers defined inside a subpackage like for ex : controllers>package1>AumController , then the corresponding reverse path is ... controllers.package1.routes.AumController

Comment: Nop. All the controllers are defined directly under the controllers package directly but still routes doesn't pick them up.

Comment: I also get the error `value uploadDo is not a member of controllers.ReverseAumController` something weird happens that not all the controller functions are generated.

Comment: Once re-build your application and give a try

Comment: I did that of course, it is a bit strange some methods do get generated and some not ... maybe it generates only those referenced from `conf/routes`

Comment: yes ofcourse routes object reverse maps methods to their corresponding uri path using routes file

Comment: as a workaround .. you can use inbuilt guice di framework  to inject the controllers into the application controller